# How to create a list of components which update independed out of an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, reducers

I have a list of objects in an Array which i load as an initial state in the reducer. 
When I research a Object in that array (increase a level by 1) the whole rendered list updates even though the rest is staying the same. 
Is there a way to only update the one component in that list within Redux?

**Reducer**

```
const researchObj = fromJS{
        researchList: [{
        id: 1,
        name: 'iron',
        level: 0
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: 'defence',
        level: 0
    }]
})

export default function (state = researchObj, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'RESEARCH':
            return research(state, action.researchId);
    }
    return state;
}

function research(state, researchId) {

    const researchObjIndex = state.get('researchList').findIndex(
        (research) => research.get('id') === researchId
    );
    let researchedItem = state.get('researchList').get(researchObjIndex);
    researchedItem = researchedItem.update('level', level => level + 1);
    let newState = state.update('researchList', researchList => researchList.set(researchObjIndex, researchedItem));
    return newState;

}
```

**ResearchList Container**

```
export class ResearchList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        this.getResearchCost = (baseCost, costIncrease, level) => {
            return baseCost + (baseCost * costIncrease * level);
        }
        return <section className={styles.root}>
            {this.props.researchList.map(item =>
                <ResearchItem
                    key={item.get('id') }
                    id={item.get('id') }
                    name={item.get('name') }
                    level={item.get('level') }
                    baseProduction={item.get('baseProduction') }
                    productionIncrease={item.get('productionIncrease') }
                    upgradeCost={this.getResearchCost(item.get('baseCost'), item.get('costIncrease'), item.get('level')) }
                    doResearch={this.props.research}
                    />
            ) }
        </section>
    }

}
ResearchList.propTypes = {
    researchList: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    research: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired

}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        researchList: state.game.get('researchList')
    };
}
export const ResearchListContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(ResearchList);
```

**ResearchItem Component**

```
export default class ResearchItem extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return <div className={styles.root}>
            <div className={styles.stats_container}>
                <span className={styles.stats_item}>Current Level: {this.props.level}</span>
                <span className={styles.stats_item}>Current Production: {(this.props.level * this.props.productionIncrease) + this.props.baseProduction}</span>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.research_btn_container}>
                <button className={styles.research_btn} onClick={() => this.props.doResearch(this.props.id) } >{this.props.name} ({this.props.upgradeCost}) </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "update"? Also if you mean render, why is that bad?

Comment: If i would have long list of in this case ResearchItems then I would not want to update the whole list if I research one. With update I mean the updates which the React chrome dev tool displays me when I activate it and also the call of the render function ( I added a console.log in it).

Comment: Not sure which update you mean for the dev tools but just know that if there are no changes to display, React is smart enough to be efficient so I wouldn't spend too much time trying to stop a re-render.

Comment: I meant the "Trace React updates".

Comment: Found the issue with the dev tools [issue on github](https://github.com/facebook/react-devtools/issues/337)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way to selectively update a component based on a store change is to set `mapStateToProps` to the appropriate part of the store. In your case you have an array that the Container needs access to so you can't restrict store updates any further. Instead what I recommend is adding a `shouldComponentUpdate` to your `ResearchItem` component. In there, you can check the `newProps` versus `this.props` and make an equality check. If the property you care about changes, let it update, otherwise don't.

Spec on `shouldComponentUpdate`:

Takes `nextProps, nextState`. It expects a return boolean so you can say,

```
return nextProps.level !== this.props.level;
```

This means it'll only update if the levels are different. Use whatever conditional you think is appropriate.

Comment: How do I stop the update. (Sorry I'm new to React and Redux).